# Prioritising and Ordering Posts By Category Name Using A Custom Loop

Tags: wp-query, customization, query, get-posts

I have a custom loop pulling out videos all assigned to various categories. However there is a category called "new-video" and I need to pull out all videos using my custom loop, but I would like the posts assigned to the category "new-video" to be shown first.

So basically the loop will treat the category "new-video" as of high priority and then show the other videos afterwards. I know you can include and exclude categories, but I don't want to exclude anything, merely prioritise.

With Wordpress 3.1 *meta_query* was introduced which allows for some pretty customisable queries, but the documentation is sparse and all of my searches thus far have returned nothing I can use.

The code I am currently using is the below if it helps:

```
$videos = get_posts(array(
 'post_type' => 'videos',
 'nopaging' => true,
 'each_connected' => array(
    'post_type' => 'artists',
    'nopaging'  => true,
 ),
 'suppress_filters' => false
));
```

Ignore the each_connected stuff, that is there because I am using the plugin [Posts to Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) by Scribu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run 2 queries, the first to pull just the new-videos and the 2nd to pull everything else but the new-videos.  Probably just use WP_Query for the first one to get the new-videos and then alter the loop query for the 2nd one to exclude new-videos.

Comment: Genius and simple. I feel kind of stupid I didn't work this out myself, but it makes sense and I think I may have done the same thing on an older project about 6 months back. Thank you Paul.